# Webscraping Instagram Likes with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, instagram

I'm trying to scrape informations about likes from instagram with Python and Selenium.

I have the following situation :
[image: Image-likes]

I want to scrape the number "63".

I have the following source code (with inspect).

[image: source code]

I tried many attempt to scrape the number "63" with selenium : by class name, by xpath...

For example :

```
Likes=browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath").text
```

In this case, I have "None" result.

With other attemps, I have nothing, or "None" : I'm not able to select the 63.

How can I do with selenium (I don't want to use BS4).

Comment: The string 'xpath' is not a valid xpath. Use developer tools to get the xpath you're looking for.

Comment: Try refreshing the page to see if the class name for the same element changes. If so, there might be some anti-scraping thing that mess up the class name. Try searching by type `button`

Comment: For the path, I writed it like this to make it readable. The real one is very long. There is no anti scraping thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
 //div[@class="Nm9Fw"]//button[contains(@type,'button')]//span
```